# How to set arrow position according to heading in vehicle tracking system

Tags: google-maps, gps, bing-maps, direction, heading

In the live tracking my GPS device sent me the heading for Bing and Google Map. On Based on that I use the arrow Image. but many time it show the wrong direction. How can I set image automatically.
Code like 
**If heading=10 then strImage="Image/10.jpg"**

Is there any option to set the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to do this.

**Use a lot of images:**

This is the approach you have indicated in your question. This consists of creating a bunch of arrow icons and then choosing the one that is closest to the GPS heading. This approach will work ok, but is only as good as the number of images you have. This approach is a lot of work and not the best option.

**The CSS3 approach:**

Start with an image of an arrow that points up. Then use the CSS3 transform to rotate the image. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Simply apply a CSS style to your pushpin that consists of:

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform: rotate([heading]deg)
```

The transform origin specifies that the transform rotation should occur around the center of the image.

Note that this approach will only work if you can use CSS with your pushpins. Some map controls let you, but newer map controls that use the HTML5 canvas don't support CSS on the pushpins. The above will work with IE10 and above. For IE9 you need to add a two more CSS styles that start with -ms-, similar things need to be done to support other older browsers.

**The HTML5 Canvas Approach:**

Similar to the CSS approach, but generates an image data URL allowing you to use this image in any map application that allows you to pass a URL as a custom pushpin (most if not all map controls). This method consists of creating an HTML5 canvas in memory, rotating it and drawing the arrow image on it, and then retrieving the data URL from the canvas and passing it in as the URL to an image. I wrote about this approach a while back in this blog (about halfway down): http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/04/10/html5-canvas-pushpins-in-javascript

This approach works with IE9 and above, and just about any browser that supports the HTML5 canvas.